# Http URLConnection wait for inner request

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am working on a crawling project.  When I do a simple `URLConnection` connection to the website as shown in below:

> URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
>               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

The method returns the HTML body correctly.  However, the website makes inner requests for some fields.  For example, the website fetches the total number of users from a different web service.  In the web browser, the total number of users appear after some time, but with the `URLConnection` method does not wait for the total number of users and the returned HTML does not contain such field.

In Java, is there any way to wait for a while to fetch all the data from a website using `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your "inner requests" comment it sounds like the website is using JavaScript (via a framework or just using native browser APIs) to fetch data and render these results into the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Web_browsers). This is very common nowadays with [SPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) etc.

If that's the case, no amount of waiting will change the outcome from using a simple HTTP library like `URLConnection` - but you can check this by saving the HTML locally and viewing it in your browser - what happens? When you examine it, is there JavaScript on that page?

To do this properly in code, you'll need something capable of behaving more like a browser, and executing that JS referenced by the HTML in a DOM-like environment. Try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or headless Chrome / Firefox, or maybe [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).

Comment: Interesting, when I debug the code, `URLConnection` returns the full body, but at runtime no.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you are getting the html body of the page, all calls made onn the server side of this web site must have been completed.

Comment: Otherwise that means the server is still processing the page for the html output.

Answer (score 0):

If the website does not contain Javascript, then use the Jsoup (https://jsoup.org) library for Java. It loads all inner HTML requests needed to render the final HTML page.