# Preloading a website before fetching HTML from the URL

Tags: java

I'm trying to get data off of a URL, but the information I need takes a few seconds to load, and only shows as LOADING in the HTML until it does load, so when I use this code I can't pull the data I need.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.cardservices.uga.edu/fs_mobile/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(lineNumber +": "+ line); 
}
```

How could I go about allowing the URL to load for a set amount of time before pulling the HTML off of it?

Comment: Great question, but a possible duplicate of [Http URLConnection wait for inner request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621143/http-urlconnection-wait-for-inner-request)

Comment: On taking a look at [link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), which should be used to hint a client on the context the given URL is to the current content, you might find a link-relation such as `prefetch` which allows a client to load and cache the content of the annotated URI a-priori. Do not confuse it with `preload` which just tells the client to load a certain resource early in the rendering processes of the current resource without blocking rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working alternate,

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.cardservices.uga.edu/fs_mobile/index.php/dashboard/occupancies/"); //This is the AJAX call that goes to load the data into webpage. You can get this from inspecting the network calls.
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line); 
    }
```

Which basically gives you the JSON response containing the percentage.

Hope it helps.

Also, you can use Selenium for performing wait if you are so curious to get the exact HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

The webpage you are calling probably call an ajax call to fetch the data, thats why you won't get it using your approach.

You have 2 options to get that data:

1. Use browser's inspect elements(F12 in chrome) and in "network" tab, get that ajax call, and use it instead of the URL you are using in your code.
2. Call your URL using a headless library(e.g ghoustjs) and after page is load crawl the data.

IMO I would choose option 1